# Centos 7, I thought "yum install ___" was supposed to get all the dependencies, too?

Tags: centos, yum, libraries, dependencies, shared-library

I want to install Trillian onto my CentOS 7 box.  I went to www.trillian.im/get/linux/6.1/linux.html and downloaded the rpm package trillian-6.1.0.5-1.fc25.x86_64.rpm.

It was my understanding that using:

```
$ yum install trillian-6.1.0.5-1.fc25.x86_64.rpm
```

would install the package and also check for and retrieve any other files needed to resolve dependencies.  It apparently didn't find any:

```
Marking trillian-6.1.0.5-1.fc25.x86_64.rpm to be installed
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package trillian.x86_64 0:6.1.0.5-1.fc25 will be installed
--> Finished Dependency Resolution

Dependencies Resolved

================================================================================
 Package    Arch     Version            Repository                         Size
================================================================================
Installing:
 trillian   x86_64   6.1.0.5-1.fc25     /trillian-6.1.0.5-1.fc25.x86_64    30 M

Transaction Summary
================================================================================
Install  1 Package

.
.
.

Installed:
  trillian.x86_64 0:6.1.0.5-1.fc25                                              

Complete!
```

However, when I try to run the program, I get this:

```
$ trillian
trillian: /lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found (required by trillian)
trillian: /lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.20' not found (required by trillian)
```

I've tried to find a way to download those specific libraries.

Comment: Consider `yum install trillian`

Answer (score 6):

#### Commentary on YUM & deps

YUM does do this. But it's only as good as the RPM specifies. In this case your RPM states that it'll work with any GLIBC > 2.13 but it clearly was built with a specific version of GLIBC, and will only work if the appropriate GCC symbols are available on the system:

```
$ rpm -qpR trillian-6.1.0.5-1.fc25.x86_64.rpm
atkmm >= 2.22.0
cairo >= 1.12.0
cairomm >= 1.10.0
gdk-pixbuf2 >= 2.26.0
glib2 >= 2.30.0
glibc >= 2.13
glibmm24 >= 2.32.0
gtk3 >= 3.4.0
gtkmm30 >= 3.4.0
libX11 >= 1.5.0
libXScrnSaver >= 1.2.0
libnotify >= 0.7.5
librsvg2-tools >= 2.36.0
libsigc++20 >= 2.2.10
libzip >= 0.10.0
openssl-libs >= 1:1.0.1
pango >= 1.30.0
pangomm >= 2.28.0
rpmlib(CompressedFileNames) <= 3.0.4-1
rpmlib(FileDigests) <= 4.6.0-1
rpmlib(PayloadFilesHavePrefix) <= 4.0-1
rpmlib(PayloadIsXz) <= 5.2-1
zlib >= 1.2.0
```

You can use `rpm -qpR <rpm>` to determine what dependencies it requires.

#### More on your issue

The heart of your issue is you're attempting to use a package that was built using a different version of the GCC compiler vs. what run time libraries are actually available on your OS.

In your case you're on CentOS 7.x and you really cannot mix RPMs across Fedora & CentOS like this, or at least you shouldn't.

If you look at what package owns that shared library:

```
$ rpm -qf /lib64/libstdc++.so.6
libstdc++-4.8.5-28.el7_5.1.x86_64
```

You can also investigate the shared library itself to see what GCC symbols it supports:

```
$ nm -D /lib64/libstdc++.so.6 | grep -i GLIBC | head -5
0000000000000000 A GLIBCXX_3.4
0000000000000000 A GLIBCXX_3.4.1
0000000000000000 A GLIBCXX_3.4.10
0000000000000000 A GLIBCXX_3.4.11
0000000000000000 A GLIBCXX_3.4.12
```

And finally look to see if it includes the ones that this RPM's binaries is looking for:

```
$ nm -D /lib64/libstdc++.so.6 | grep -iE '3\.4\.20|3\.4\.21'
$
```

No surprises here, this `.so` library doesn't include the symbols for either of those versions of GCC, hence the error.

#### What to do?

The typical ways you deal with this are either:

1. Get a binary built against your GCC's symbol definitions
2. Get just the `libstdc++.so.6` library from some other tool (many apps opt to include libraries for easier deployment/setup/installation) and point to it via your `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. You typically do it like this:

   ```
   $ LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path/to/lib trillian
   ```
3. Run the app in a VM
4. Run the app in a Docker container
5. Get a version of the RPM that has binaries that were built using symbols that are consistent with your OS's GCC setup.

Given the similarities between Fedora & CentOS I've had good success with many of the above. You could try #5, and try one of the older Fedora RPMs on their website to see if it was built with CentOS's version of GCC symbols.

#### References

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_C_Library
- [How To Write Shared Libraries](https://software.intel.com/sites/default/files/m/a/1/e/dsohowto.pdf)
- [Static, Shared Dynamic and Loadable Linux Libraries](http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/LibraryArchives-StaticAndDynamic.html)

Answer (score 3):

`yum` resolves dependencies concerning other packages. In other words, it installs packages which are depended on by the package(s) that you are trying to install.

The error that you are receiving is due to the fact that the library file, /lib64/libstdc++.so.6, does not include `GLIBCXX_3.4.20` or `GLIBCXX_3.4.21`. Usually, /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6 is a symlink to /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.# where # is the highest version of GLIBCXX inside.

If you run this command, you'll see the versions of GLIBCXX which are included:

```
strings /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6 | grep -i ^glibcxx_
```

As you don't have it, you will need to install a package which contains those libraries.

The easiest package to install that provides it is:

Anaconda3

You can download it from Anaconda's website and there is a walkthrough on installing it. After it's installed, you can prepend Anaconda's library to your LD_LIBRARY_PATH. For example, if you installed it into /opt/anaconda3, then you'll add this line to your `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.bashrc`:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/anaconda3/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

You can then start a new shell session and run trillian again.

You can also source compile GCC6, GCC7, or GCC8 which will provide the correct libraries which you can then add to your path but you also have to source compile GMP, MPC, and MPFR which, in your case, is more trouble than it's worth.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you both -- your answers were very helpful.

I was unsuccessful at locating just the libstdc++ library to install, so I went with the Anaconda3 install.  This got me past that specific issue, only to present me with another one:

$ trillian
trillian: symbol lookup error: trillian: undefined symbol: _ZN4Glib25filename_display_basenameERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEE

So now I'm off to hunt down a solution for that problem.  Any suggestions are welcomed, and thank you both again for helping me get this far!